# Using Labels in HAVING() Clause in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to implement the following query for handling nested sets (see [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)) within SQLAlchemy.  What I'm struggling with is how to use the labeled `depth` calculation in the main `SELECT` query (which depends on the sub `SELECT` query) within the `HAVING` clause on the end.

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent,
    nested_category AS sub_parent,
    (
            SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
            FROM nested_category AS node,
                    nested_category AS parent
            WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                    AND node.name = 'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS'
            GROUP BY node.name
            ORDER BY node.lft
    )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
    AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth <= 1
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

I feel like I'm very close when using:

```
node = aliased(Category)                                                                             
parent = aliased(Category)                                                                           
sub_parent = aliased(Category)

sub_tree = DBSession.query(node.name,                                                                
    (func.count(parent.name) - 1).label('depth')).\                                                  
    filter(node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\                                               
    filter(node.name == category_name).\                                                             
    group_by(node.name).\                                                                            
    order_by(node.lft).subquery()                                                                    

children = DBSession.query(node.name,                                                                
    (func.count(parent.name) - (sub_tree.c.depth + 1)).label('depth')).\                             
    filter(node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    filter(node.lft.between(sub_parent.lft, sub_parent.rgt)).\                                       
    filter(sub_parent.name == sub_tree.c.name).\                                                     
    group_by(node.name).having(depth <= 1).\                                                       
    order_by(node.lft).all()
```

But, I end up getting the error:

```
NameError: global name 'depth' is not defined
```

Which sort of makes sense.  If I substitute `having(depth <= 1)` with `having(func.count('depth') <= 1`, I end up with the following `HAVING` clause generated that returns no results (Where %s placeholders are ('depth', 1)):

```
HAVING count(%s) <= %s
```

What I really need it to read exactly like is this:

```
HAVING depth = 1
```

Anybody have any ideas?

My last resort is to actually perform the raw query instead of going through the ORM layer, but I'd really rather not since I'm so close...

Thanks in advance.

***Edit:***

I have also tried the following code, but it does not return the correct results (as if the 'depth' label is always 0):

```
node = aliased(Category)                                                                             
parent = aliased(Category)                                                                           
sub_parent = aliased(Category)

sub_tree_depth = (func.count(parent.name) - 1).label('depth')
depth = (func.count(parent.name) - (sub_tree_depth + 1)).label('depth')

sub_tree = DBSession.query(node.name,
    sub_tree_depth).\
    filter(node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    filter(node.name == category_name).\
    group_by(node.name).\
    order_by(node.lft).subquery()

children = DBSession.query(node.name, 
    depth).\
    filter(node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    filter(node.lft.between(sub_parent.lft, sub_parent.rgt)).\
    filter(sub_parent.name == sub_tree.c.name).\
    group_by(node.name).having(depth <= 1).\
    order_by(node.lft).all()
```

The `HAVING` clause generated from this looks like (categories_2 == parent in original query):

```
HAVING count(categories_2.name) - ((count(categories_2.name) - 1) + 1) <= 1
```

***Edit:***

I figured it might be helpful to include the generated SQL.

***SQLAlchemy***

```
node = aliased(Category)
parent = aliased(Category)
sub_parent = aliased(Category)

sub_tree = DBSession.query(node.name,
    (func.count(parent.name) - 1).label('depth')).\
    filter(node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    filter(node.name == category_name).\
    group_by(node.name).\
    order_by(node.lft).subquery()

depth = (func.count(parent.name) - (sub_tree.c.depth + 1)).label('depth')
children = DBSession.query(node.name, depth).\
    filter(node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    filter(node.lft.between(sub_parent.lft, sub_parent.rgt)).\
    filter(sub_parent.name == sub_tree.c.name).\
    group_by(node.name).having(depth <= 1).\
    order_by(node.lft)
```

***Generated SQL***

```
'SELECT categories_1.name AS categories_1_name, count(categories_2.name) - (anon_1.depth + %s) AS depth 
FROM categories AS categories_1, categories AS categories_2, (SELECT categories_1.name AS name, count(categories_2.name) - %s AS depth 
FROM categories AS categories_1, categories AS categories_2 
WHERE categories_1.lft BETWEEN categories_2.lft AND categories_2.rgt AND categories_1.name = %s GROUP BY categories_1.name ORDER BY categories_1.lft) AS anon_1, categories AS categories_3 
WHERE categories_1.lft BETWEEN categories_2.lft AND categories_2.rgt AND categories_1.lft BETWEEN categories_3.lft AND categories_3.rgt AND categories_3.name = anon_1.name GROUP BY categories_1.name 
HAVING count(categories_2.name) - (anon_1.depth + %s) <= %s ORDER BY categories_1.lft' (1, 1, u'Institutional', 1, 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the whole depth as filter in `HAVING` clause like `HAVING (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) = 1`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I attempted to use `HAVING (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) = 1` which didn't return the correct results.  I then tried `HAVING (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) <= 1`, which resulted in a SQL error of `Unknown column 'sub_tree.depth'....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your SQL query uses implicit joins, in SQLAlchemy you need to define them explicitly.  Other than that your second try is almost correct:

```py
node = aliased(Category)
parent = aliased(Category)
sub_parent = aliased(Category)

sub_tree = DBSession.query(node.name,
    (func.count(parent.name) - 1).label('depth')).\
    join(parent, node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    filter(node.name == category_name).\
    group_by(node.name).\
    order_by(node.lft).subquery()

depth = (func.count(parent.name) - (sub_tree.c.depth + 1)).label('depth')
children = DBSession.query(node.name, depth).\
    join(parent, node.lft.between(parent.lft, parent.rgt)).\
    join(sub_parent, node.lft.between(sub_parent.lft, sub_parent.rgt)).\
    join(sub_tree, sub_parent.name == sub_tree.c.name).\
    group_by(node.name, sub_tree.c.depth).\
    having(depth <= 1).\
    order_by(node.lft).all()
```

Don't be surprised if `HAVING` clause in generated SQL will have full expression repeated instead of its alias. That's because aliases are not allowed there, it's only MySQL extension, while SQLAlchemy strives to generate SQL that works in most cases.

Comment: I really appreciate it.  However, I do get an error message `Unknown column 'anon_1.depth' in 'having clause'`.  I can't post the entire generated SQL, but here's what I think the important piece is:
`HAVING count(categories_2.name) - (anon_1.depth + 1) <= 1`

Comment: In case it wasn't apparent, SQLAlchemy is assigning `sub_tree` to `anon_1` and `categories_2` to `parent`.

Comment: I updated my answer, at first I didn't notice the missing joins... Hopefully it will work now.

Comment: I _really_ appreciate the persistence.  Unfortunately, even with the joins I get the same error message `Unknown column 'anon_1.depth' in 'having clause'`.  The generated SQL for the `HAVING` clause is the same: `HAVING count(categories_2.name) - (anon_1.depth + 1) <= 1`.  Again, I can't post the entire generated SQL, but I can verify that it's using INNER JOINS now.

Comment: OK, I did some googling and found out that `Unknown column in 'having clause'` error in MySQL means that this column must be included in `GROUP BY` clause (talk about vague error messages...). I'll update my answer to include it, but now I'm curious if your original SQL query works. Unfortunately, I don't have any MySQL installation at hand to try this out myself (I'm a Postgres guy).

Comment: You, sir, are awesome!  Thank you so much.  It works without doing the JOINS as well, by the way, so I decided not to use them.  Thanks again!